# Why is this slug a bit weird?

Tags: discussion, slug

Hi guys,

I apologize for this being a foolish question, if indeed it is.

But what is the deal with this:

[JavaScript not working inside AJAX loaded DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476064/java-script-not-working-inside-ajax-loaded-div)

I understand that sluggifiers are not perfect, but surely, java-script should be just 'javascript'.

Just wonderin' :)

Answer (score 3):

It should be, and it would be if the original poster had written 'javascript'. Instead they wrote 'java script', and the sluggifier turned the space into a dash, as it always does.

Comment: And now I feel foolish. Thank you. Maybe we need an intelligent slug condensification system. (or something)

Comment: @karim79 or someone can just edit the title to [fix the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476064/javascript-not-working-inside-ajax-loaded-div).

Comment: @Mark Trapp - Thanks. I realise that :). Additionally, I realise that I asked a dumb question. And I thank you for changing java script to JavaScript. I am an idiot.

Comment: @karim79 don't sweat it. :)